# How a sloping/leaning background colour can be set to a text with HTML-CSS

Tags: css, html, background-color

What I need to achieve is something like what appears on the following example image.[image: Sample image of sloping bg]

I need the background to grow along the text, because the texts can be dynamic, so I can't set a static image background. Also the text should be able to overlap the darker background stripe (as you can see in the "l" of "lorem" in the example) and there could be more than one line of text.

Crossbrowser solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
<div class="bottom">
    <br>
    <div class="under">
        <div class="over">
            lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.bottom {
    background-color: #bbb;
    height: 100px;
}

.under {
    background-color: #555;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.over {
    margin-left: 120px;
    color: white;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/CxmRg/

Comment: Thanks, that was usefull. (Forget to say anything before, sorry)